# Get active calories burned using Google Fit API

Tags: android, google-fit

I am working on the fitness app for android. I am fetching the calories burned from the Google fit API but it's giving me the inactive + active calories. I want only the active calories burned. Can anyone please help me out in this.

Here is the code I am using for fetching the calories burned from Google fit API:

```
private class FetchCalorieAsync extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Float> {
    protected Float doInBackground(Object... params) {
        float total = 0;
        PendingResult<DailyTotalResult> result = Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal(googleApiClient, DataType.AGGREGATE_CALORIES_EXPENDED);
        DailyTotalResult totalResult = result.await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (totalResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            DataSet totalSet = totalResult.getTotal();
            if (totalSet != null) {
                total = totalSet.isEmpty() ? 0 : totalSet.getDataPoints().get(0).getValue(Field.FIELD_CALORIES).asFloat();
            }
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "There was a problem getting the calories.");
        }
        return total;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Float aLong) {
        super.onPostExecute(aLong);
        tvCalorieBurnt.setText(String.valueOf((int)(Math.round(aLong))));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [link](http://www.gadgetsaint.com/android/active-calories-burned-google-fit/#.WU0Xk3WGNCU) here you can get how to filter out active calories (calories consumed while Running and Walking) for a particular date.